# Resizing iframe for responsive mobile

Tags: iframe, instagram, shopify

One of my clients has a shopify store and wants to include a free instagram widget on the home page. Only problem is all of the free ones use iframes ... otherwise you have to pay a monthly fee.

I feel like I've tried one million different codes to try and get the iframe to be responsive but it's just not cooperating with me. I've tried wrapping it in a div, setting widths and heights to a percentage ... nothing is working. Plus I'm finding Shopify extremely difficult to modify as it is.

The website is ospeak.com.au and it's currently using the statigram iconosquare widget.

I was thinking maybe as a solution was to set different widths depending on screen size? So it's more of a forced responsive that fluid?

Comment: Please provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [codepen](http://codepen.io/) with the iframe and specific details of what you have tried.

Comment: Instagram widget is responsive by default. It has a width of 100% meaning it fits itself inside of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can insert some code on the iconosquare page you don't have much hope. If you do there are several things you could do but why not check out http://instafeedjs.com/? That should allow you to achieve your goal quite a bit more easily than hacking around with an iframe.